# Need advice on handling multiple threads in android service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I've been trying to implement an `android service` that can download an audio stream into a file & then can play that file simultaneously.

This way I can also implement buffering.

I'm using multiple threads. So tried my hands on `ExecutorService` for the first time.

Code is [here on github](https://github.com/rahulsaini8/android), with lots of comments for explanation.

It downloads and plays stream perfectly for sometime but after few moments (say after 1 or 2 mins) it stops **without throwing any exception & does not even print anything in logs either**.

**Code Explanation:**

Main class to focus is ServiceExecutor which is an android Service.

1. It first starts an AsyncTask to initiate the entire process. In which it:
2. Setups the the temporary file where the file will be downloaded.
3. Starts a thread to fetch the duration of the stream in background. This duration will be useful while buffering.
   Note this thread will not play the stream.
4. Starts a second thread that will download the stream into the temporary file.
5. Starts a third thread to play the stream from the file.
6. This third thread will internally in its MediaPlayer's onPrepared() function will also start forth thread to handle the buffering of the stream.

By buffering I mean, recursively checking if the file has enough data to continuously play the stream.
In every call it checks if the temp file has less than 2 sec stream remaining & the file is still downloading then pause the media player for 5 seconds.
It maintains a variable 'pausedAtMilliSec' which records where the stream is paused so that if the player also abruptly stops, it can be resumed from there.

As you can see by now I'm not very good in threading.
Seems to me, the problem is with multiple thread handling (seems, but not sure).

So feel free to post **any** comment or advice. I'll not feel bad, rather be happy.

Please check the code once.

I'm aware of the [PocketJourney's](http://www.infidian.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/) code. But want to try mine too.

*Thank You*

Comment: you might want to look at some of the alternate protocols ( streaming ) providing better support for what you want to do...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP

Comment: @RobertRowntree - I'll look into your suggestion. But again really want to know what am I doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: @WilliamSeemann - I've handled the premature completion in code & it is working. But when the error occurs the app's UI gets stuck & eclipse(in debug mode) just opens ThreadPoolExecutor class. And then if I press F8 then app shows error dialog box & quits. Thanks